# Installed c++ app in usr/local/bin of Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't run correctly when executed from home directory

Tags: c++, ubuntu, installation

I have created a deb package out of an c++ programm . I followed this simple guide https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=910717. I installed the deb at usr/local/bin successfully.
However I'm facing the following problem. When I run my app from home directory c++ main program starts but when it reaches a point where it needs to read from a settings file it acts as if it does not exist. This file resides in a folder which is in the same place with the c++ executable.
On the other hand when I go to -> usr/local/bin and run my c++ app from there no problem exist. I also have given read write and execute permissions to all files.
Since the /usr/local/bin already exist in my path why this error occurs?

Comment: Your file is given by a relative path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the application has the current path as your path, not where it's installed. you need to figure out the application path to load the file correctly - if you use Qt you have applicationPath, if not you have to:

```
char szTmp[32];
sprintf(szTmp, "/proc/%d/exe", getpid());
int bytes = MIN(readlink(szTmp, pBuf, len), len - 1);
if(bytes >= 0)
        pBuf[bytes] = '\0';
return bytes;
```

to determine the application installation folder and load the file based on that.

Comment: thanks for your quick response. Currently I'using poco library and especially Poco::Path::current() in order to build the path for the settings file. So  you mean that even though it is installed in usr/local/bin , when I run from home directory the Poco::Path::current() returns the home directory?

Comment: exacrly. current() is the current directory, not the installed path.

Comment: Thanks again. One last question since I have no previous experience regarding linux install. Since the app will be installed in a specific location which I choose will it be inefficient to load the absolute path of /usr/local/bin/c++app. Are there any disadvantages regarding that approach?

Comment: that's negligible. :)